# Fill table in Entity Framework Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

One of my EF migrations creates a table and as part of the migration `Up` method I would like to fill this table with initial data.

Here's my migration class:

```
public partial class Objects : DbMigration
{
    void Fill(string table, string path, string fieldTerminator = ",", string rowTerminator = @"\n")
    {
        Sql(string.Format("BULK INSERT {0} FROM '{1}' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '{2}', ROWTERMINATOR = '{3}')", table, path, fieldTerminator, rowTerminator));
    }

    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Objects",
            c => new
                {
                    ObjectId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(),
                    Location_X = c.Double(nullable: false),
                    Location_Y = c.Double(nullable: false),
                    Location_Z = c.Double(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ObjectId);

        Fill("dbo.Objects", @"C:\temp\Scratch\Junk\ConsoleApplication3\data\objects.csv");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.Objects");
    }
}
```

This works correctly on my machine from the Package Manager Console. However I would like to use a relative path for the file so that the entire development team can use this easily.

When I simply wrote the file name the update failed. When I tried concatenating the current directory to the file name I saw that the current directory was c:\windows\system32.

How can I make the update run from the project or solution directory?

Alternatively, is there a better way to fill the table during an update? I don't want to use the `Seed` method becasue it doesn't do exactly what I want. For instance, there's only a single `Seed` method while I want to write different code for different migrations.

Comment: What does this `Fill`method do? I'm a bit surprised it works, because the migration methods only _define_ migrations and don't execute them. Couldn't you do the same in the `Seed`method (read a file and load it).

Comment: use `\\localhost\temp\Scratch\...`, poeple need only have temp share on their machine and it would work   ie the need to share the temp directory as `temp` and place the file there

Comment: @GertArnold The `Fill` method bulk inserts data from a file into the DB. You can see that I call it from the `Up` method. It works, so I don't ask why :-) As for the `Seed` method, like I said, I don't want to use it becasue it isn't associated with e particular migration. Also, I'm pretty sure it will work slower than bulk adding from a file.

Comment: @philsoady I want to keep the file with the initial data in our source control, rather than in a shared location.

Comment: @ Dina: use a share on source machine.   eg `temp`  then all access this via UNC  `\\TheSourceMachineName\temp\.....`  a way to access to a central server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a **workaround** you may get path to the current source file and then to enter to relative path of the CSV file with data.

Meaning instead of:

```
dataFile = @"C:\temp\Scratch\Junk\ConsoleApplication3\data\objects.csv";
```

Have something like:

```
currentFile = GetSourceFilePath(); // See below hints for implementation
dataFile = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(currentFile),
    @"..\data\objects.csv"
);
```

Here are some examples of how exactly to get access to source file path - [Print the source filename and linenumber in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369184/print-the-source-filename-and-linenumber-in-c-sharp).

Comment: This is working only if the DB sits on the same server!