# Is it possible to see the MVC View structure from within a browser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, razor, browser, partial-views

Is it possible to see the MVC View structure from within a browser?
As in, is it possible to enable some configuration that will show you the file name of each View and Partial view being rendered from within a browser?

i.e.

If I had Index.cshtml, which then renders two partial views Content1.cshtml and Content2.cshtml, then I would like to see the file names from the F12 browser tool:

```
//Index.cshtml
<html> .....
....
//Content1.cshtml
<table> ... </table>
//Content2.cshtml
<div> ... </div>

</html>
```

Comment: Use BrowserLink

Comment: @SLaks And then ... ? I can see this inside my F12: <script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData"> {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"...."}
</script> ... where am I supposed to be looking?

Comment: http://vswebessentials.com/features/browserlink

Comment: @SLaks I like this approach but it doesn't work for me ... we are using knockout and it is complaining with an error in the browserlink.js file: ``Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[data-bind='value: Vendor.Agent.Name, attr: {name: 'request.Vendor.Agent.Name'}, valueUpdate: ['click', 'change', 'input']']

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the Caller Info attributes.

Create new `ViewFileName` function:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IHtmlString ViewFileName([CallerFilePath]string filePath = "unknown")
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString("<!-- " + Path.GetFileName(filePath) + " -->");
    }
}
```

Then call it in every regular and partial view:

```
@Extensions.ViewFileName()
```

For more information check [Caller Information (C#) documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653988.aspx), [Creating Custom HTML Helpers (C#) article](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) by Microsoft ASP.NET Team and [Print the source filename and linenumber in C# question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369184/print-the-source-filename-and-linenumber-in-c-sharp).

Comment: This works but it's not what I'm looking for, if there are 20 partial views and I have to place code inside all of them, then I will most likely find the place that I want to find and I would not be saving any time ... I can usually always find the place but I wanted to make the process faster.

Comment: Do you use `Html.RenderPartial` to render partial views?

Comment: Yes, the majority of times.