# log4net writes '?' when I use `%type, %method and %line` patterns

Tags: asp.net, log4net

I'm trying to use the log4net in my c# ASP.net Core 2.2 app but when I use any of these patterns they give me output with question marks.

**My log4net.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\Temp\app.log" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <conversionPattern value="%date | %level | [%thread] | %type %method %line - %message%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

the file looks like this after a log is written:

```
2019-04-17 11:48:44,230 | INFO | [1] | ? ? ? - abc
```

any idea why this is happening and how to fix this?
I saw some tutorials that use these patterns and tried to copy from them but the results were the same... maybe something in my configuration is wrong?

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369184/print-the-source-filename-and-linenumber-in-c-sharp) I understand that I can just add the file name and line to my message but I wanted to try a fix in the config file first.

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I copy-paste your configuration to my project and it works as expected. Did you run your project in Release or Debug? Did you read about limitations in those patterns?

> Note about caller location information. The following patterns `%type
>   %file %line %method %location %class %C %F %L %l %M` all generate
>   caller location information. Location information uses the
>   `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` class to generate a call stack. The
>   caller's information is then extracted from this stack.
>
> The `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` class is **not supported on the 
>   .NET Compact Framework 1.0** therefore caller location information is
>   not available on that framework.
>
> The `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` class has this to say about
>   Release builds:
>
> StackTrace information will be most informative with Debug build
>   configurations.  By default, Debug builds include debug symbols, while
>   Release builds do not. The  debug symbols contain most of the file,
>   method name, line number, and column  information used in constructing
>   StackFrame and StackTrace objects. StackTrace  might not report as
>   many method calls as expected, due to code transformations  that occur
>   during optimization.
>
> **This means that in a Release build the caller information may be**
>   **incomplete or may  not exist at all!** Therefore caller location
>   information cannot be relied upon in a Release build.

**Edit**

In .net core / .net standard StackTrace isn't fully supported:

https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/master/src/Core/LocationInfo.cs#L86

So `className`, `fileName`, `lineNumber`, `methodName`, `fullInfo` are not available.

Comment: updated my question, I`m using ASP.net core 2.2 and I'm running my project in debug